# click a button for each item, change color to green

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a list with questions, per question you can select answer A, B or nothing. What I have so far is that when a button is clicked the color change to green. I want to implement this for each question item. How can I do this?

```
<ion-item class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async>
   <button> (click)="itemClicked(item.AnswerA)" [class.active]="selectedItem == item.AnswerA">Answer A</button>
   <button> (click)="itemClicked(item.AnswerA)" [class.active]="selectedItem == item.AnswerB">Answer B</button>
</ion-item>

itemClicked(item) {
  this.selectedItem = item;
}

.active {
        background-color: green;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `Answer A` and `Answer B` buttons class.active are based on only one `selectedItem`. You can add a `selectedItem` to each of your question, and do the below changes:

```
<ion-item class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async>
  <button> (click)="itemClicked(item, item.AnswerA)" [class.active]="item.selectedItem == item.AnswerA">Answer A</button>
  <button> (click)="itemClicked(item, item.AnswerA)" [class.active]="item.selectedItem == item.AnswerB">Answer B</button>
</ion-item>
```

itemClicked function:

```
itemClicked(item, answer) {
  // keep selectedItem for each item
  item.selectedItem = answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now the way to do it is:

```
<button [attr.newColor]="addAttribute ? '' : null">Test</button>
```

So if addAttribute evaluates to true it will add the newColor attribute, and if it evaluates to false it won't add the attribute at all.

The conference app has an example here using the mode: 
[Changing button color or icon dynamically](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/changing-button-color-or-icon-dynamically/37675)